# Get list of all compartments in OCI Tenancy

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

I am trying to get the list of all `compartments` (including child compartments) in `OCI Tenancy` using `Python SDK`.

But the below `OCI API` does not give the `root compartment` details.

Is there a way to get `root compartment` details via any API directly?

Below is my code:

```
import oci
from oci.config import from_file
from oci.signer import Signer

config = from_file()

COMPARTMENT_ID="ocid1.tenancy.oc1..a"

identity_client = oci.identity.IdentityClient(config)

list_compartments_response = identity_client.list_compartments(
    compartment_id=COMPARTMENT_ID,
    compartment_id_in_subtree=True)

compartmentlist = list_compartments_response.data
```

`compartmentlist` dict does not contain the `root compartment` details.

Please help.

Edit 1:

`COMPARTMENT_ID` given above in the code is the `root compartment ID`. I need the details of even this `root compartment` in the final response of API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list_compartments` gives details of all the `sub-compartments` under a particular `compartment OCID` provided to the API.

If you are providing `root compartment OCID` to this API then it will give all the `compartment` details under `root compartment` excluding the `root`.

For appending the `root compartment` details, below API can be used. I am not aware of any other `OCI API` to accomplish this task.

Hope this helps you.

```
import oci
from oci.config import from_file

config = from_file()  # Config file is read from user's home location i.e., ~/.oci/config

COMPARTMENT_ID="ocid1.tenancy.oc1..a" # root compartment OCID

identity_client = oci.identity.IdentityClient(config)

list_compartments_response = identity_client.list_compartments(
    compartment_id=COMPARTMENT_ID,
    compartment_id_in_subtree=True)

# Get the list of compartments including child compartments except root compartment
compartmentlist = list_compartments_response.data

# Get the details of root compartment & append to the compartment list so that we have the full list of compartments in the given tenancy

root_compartment = identity_client.get_compartment(
    compartment_id=COMPARTMENT_ID).data
compartmentlist.append(root_compartment)
```